# Publish C# unit test results from running docker container to azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, docker

I want to publish/copy a unit test result output (.trx file generated by dotnet test CLI command) from a running docker container to azure blob storage. Can someone please assist me?

Comment: `docker cp container_name:/path/myfile.trx . && az storage blob upload \
    --container-name mystoragecontainer \
    --name blobName \
    --file  myfile.trx` `

Comment: Thank you Adiii for the quick response.. Does the below image cover azure CLI command as well? Can I execute "az storage blob upload" command by using below image as a base image?

"docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch"

Comment: if you not you can install one

Comment: btw you can run the command from host machine

Comment: What you do really want? Run the CLI command inside the docker container? Or just want to copy the file from the docker container to the azure storage blob?

Comment: Run the Azure CLI command inside the docker container to copy/publish unit test results into azure blob storage

Comment: Any more update for the question? If you need more help please let me know. If you solve the problem with the solution please accept it.

Comment: Hi Charles,

Thank you for your help. I changed my approach now and not going to use the Azure CLI command to publish test results. I will let you know if I need more help

Comment: I'm glad to help you. But if you change the requirement different from the description in this problem. You need to accept this answer if it works for this problem. And then you need to aks another problem for your different requirement.

Answer (score 0):

According to the message that you provide, you want to run the Azure CLI command inside the docker container to achieve the actions you want. So you need to install the Azure CLI when you create the docker image. For that purpose, you can choose the [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) according to the operating system you use.